# Getting error on live environment while connecting with Oracle Cloud Autonomous Transaction Processing Using wallet

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

The application is developed on VS 2015 Express. The same connection string is connected to my local system but on live environment, it is giving me  error. Please help me out.

Error Message: ProviderIncompatibleException

Exception Type: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException

Error Location : An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.

Error Page Url: http://10.0.17.3:8081/

Comment: The error page you mentioned is a local ip, not a public ip. We can not access it. Where is you live environment hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there's a different Oracle TNS_ADMIN location and wallet location for the live environment vs. the dev environment. You can set the wallet location in the .NET code or in sqlnet.ora. The TNS_ADMIN can be set in the code or as a Windows environment variable.

This error is fairly generic. If you can identify an inner exception or provider specific error code, it would be easier to identify the root cause of the problem.